# Responding to server response

Tags: visual-studio-2010, c#-4.0, webbrowser-control

I'm using WebBrowser control functionality to implement web browser capabilities in my project. Is there a way that when my browser (which I have developed by using WebBrowser control) sends a request to a server (lets say to download a file), instead of the browser handling the response, I would be able to handle it myself in my project?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Check out the WebBrowser events on msdn (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ayestehw.aspx). There is a Navigating event you can handle (and cancel), but that cancels before the request is made. I don't know if you'll be able to handle the response after it is received, but before the WebBrowser control reacts. There is also a FileDownloaded event if you are only interested in downloaded files.